# Are there any good build frameworks written in Python?

Tags: python, build-process, build-automation

I switched from NAnt to using Python to write build automation scripts.  I am curious if whether any build frameworks worth using that are similar to Make, Ant, and NAnt, but, instead, are Python-based.  For example, Ruby has Rake.  What about Python?

Comment: note also this near-duplicate: [build automation - Is there an Rake equivalent in Python? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407837/is-there-an-rake-equivalent-in-python)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try [SCons](http://www.scons.org/)

Or are you looking for something just to build python projects?

Comment: Not necessarily. I want something that can also build any non-Python projects. NAnt, Ant, and Rake have that versatility and are not limited to their own language domain.

Comment: I think you should give scons a try, then.

Comment: I agree... you have to spend a little bit of time with scons, it's more powerful than it seems at first glance.  It works from the simplest description of what you want, and where the source is, and will do the right thing.

Comment: I use SCons in a large production project and have found it to be very customizable and useful.  Highly recommended.

Comment: I use SCons, but its jus so slow when you get to a bug project.  Seriously, look at something like WAF, it's much much quicker than SCons, if a little-less mature.

Comment: @jkp, if you really need that speed, it is possible to integrate Python with [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) or FB `watchman`, but this is job for hackers. =)

Answer (score 5):

The following look good, but I haven't used them (yet):

- [Paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/)
- [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/)
- [doIt](http://python-doit.sourceforge.net/)

Paver looks especially promising.

Answer (score 3):

[The Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org) maintains a page [on python build and deployment tools](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigurationAndBuildTools).

Answer (score 2):

My Rapid Throughts:
SCons is quite mature and oriented also to other languages (es C++)
Waf is very simlar to ant/maven, so you will prefer it if you are used to ant/maven

Paver is very pythonic oriented, and seems a good option if you do not know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Fabric](http://www.nongnu.org/fab/) but it's specially geared towards deployment rather than generic *building*.