# Is there a Rake equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, build-automation

Rake is a software build tool written in Ruby (like [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) or [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29)), and so all its files are written in this language. Does something like this exist in Python?

Comment: Are you looking for a general dependency resolution and build tool, like make, which can build projects from any language? Or something to build python packages specifically?

Comment: Something general. Building Python package is interesting, but can be performed with general tools.

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542289/are-there-any-good-build-frameworks-written-in-python

Comment: also see http://farmdev.com/thoughts/46/the-python-make-tool/

Comment: Did anyone came here from Joe Armstrong slide?
https://youtu.be/lKXe3HUG2l4?t=1270

Comment: Wondering what are current opinions on Paver vs Invoke vs Doit https://pydoit.org/ ... the  main contenders that are still active, and mentioned in answers below?
Is there a good comparison somewhere out there?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Paver](https://github.com/paver/paver/) has a similar set of goals, though I don't really know how it compares.

Comment: That seems definitly the closest.

Comment: That seems to have [lost momentum in 2011](http://paver.github.io/paver/changelog.html#changelog)

Comment: The project is still active, the changelog is now here: https://pythonhosted.org/Paver/changelog.html

Comment: Latest version at https://pythonhosted.org/Paver/changelog.html is `1.1.0 (July 30, 2012)`

Comment: Any opinions on Invoke (mentioned in other answers on this Q), vs Paver? are they direct "competitors"? Pros/Cons?

Answer (score 41):

[Invoke](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/) — [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest) without the SSH dependencies.

The [Fabric roadmap](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/roadmap.html) discusses that [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest) 1.x will be split into three portions:

1. [Invoke](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/) — The non-SSH task execution.
2. [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest) 2.x — The remote execution and deployment library that utilizes [Invoke](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/).
3. [Patchwork](https://github.com/fabric/patchwork) — The "common deployment/sysadmin operations, built on Fabric."

Invoke is a Python (2.6+ and 3.3+) task execution tool & library, drawing inspiration from various sources to arrive at a powerful & clean feature set.

Below are a few descriptive statements from [Invoke](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/)'s website:

> - Invoke is a Python (2.6+ and 3.3+) task execution tool & library, drawing inspiration from various sources to arrive at a powerful & clean feature set.
> - Like Ruby’s Rake tool and Invoke’s own predecessor Fabric 1.x, it provides a clean, high level API for running shell commands and defining/organizing task functions from a tasks.py file.

Comment: @IgorZevaka now it works on windows, the same topic - github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/pull/119

Comment: Was Shovel user some 4 years ago. Definitely go with Invoke now. Very cool command-line interface, task declaration is nice and easy, chaining feels like Make's. Nice.

Comment: Any opinions on Paver (mentioned in other answers on this Q), vs Invoke? are they direct "competitors"? Pros/Cons?

Answer (score 14):

Shovel seems promising:

[Shovel — Rake for Python](http://devblog.seomoz.org/2012/03/shovel-rake-for-python/)

https://github.com/seomoz/shovel

Comment: As of 23-Dec-15, [Shovel](https://github.com/seomoz/shovel) was last updated a year ago on 5-Dec-14.

Answer (score 6):

[Waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) is a Python-based framework for configuring, compiling and installing applications. It derives from the concepts of other build tools such as Scons, Autotools, CMake or Ant.

Comment: What are the benefits of Waf other scons ?

Answer (score 5):

Although it is more commonly used for deployment, [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) might be interesting for this use case.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [doit](http://pydoit.org/) - I came across it while looking for these things a while ago, though I didn't get very far with evaluating it.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out buildout, which isn't so much a make system for software, as a make system for a deployment.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite/2.5.5

So it's not a direct rake equivalent, but may be a better match for what you want to do, or a really lousy one.

Comment: Using buildout for that is like jusing a tank to go to the mall, isn't it ? Using any Zope / Plone tools outside Zope / Plone generally is, anyway :-p

Comment: "For that"? He didn't specify what he wanted to use it for.

Anyway, buildout is not a Zope/Plone tool. It is also not big or complex. It's really quote tiring that some people will dismiss tool only because it's written by or used by Zope developers. That attitude it pretty daft.

Comment: Come on, that was just teasing. I used to work for a Plone-only company and yes, we use to make a lot of jokes about the tools we were using. That's a sane attitude, don't you think ?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Phantom](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/Phantom) in Boo (which isn't Python, but nearly).

Answer (score -2):

I would check out [`distutils`](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html):

> The `distutils` package provides support
>   for building and installing additional
>   modules into a Python installation.
>   The new modules may be either
>   100%-pure Python, or may be extension
>   modules written in C, or may be
>   collections of Python packages which
>   include modules coded in both Python
>   and C.

Comment: does it support things like documentation generation or running unit tests?